# how to get all events in cloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm a newbee here and please my poor english.
I'm testing a aws EC2 server. I configured cloudWatch
I know that get_log_events in python boto or get-log-events command in aws cli can do that. but these can only get log events partially (3~4 days only).
I want to get all events programmatically.
I have been searching for a few days but I can't.
Please help me. Thanks in advance.

fyi, let me show you my python boto3 code.

```
enter code here
logs = boto3.client('logs', 'ap-northeast-2')
for a1 in logs.describe_log_groups()['logGroups']:
    a1name = a1['logGroupName']
    for a2 in logs.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=a1name)['logStreams']:
        a2name = a2['logStreamName']
        for a3 in logs.get_log_events(logGroupName=a1name, logStreamName=a2name)['events']:
            lmf = str.split(str(a3['message']), ' ') # log message field
            print a1name, a2name, lmf[0], lmf[1], lmf[2], lmf[3], lmf[4], lmf[5], lmf[6], lmf[7], lmf[8], lmf[9], lmf[10], lmf[11], lmf[12]
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll find in the [documentation for `get_log_events()`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_log_events) that the response is paginated.  More results require subsequent requests.

> By default, this operation returns as many log events as can fit in a response size of 1MB (up to 10,000 log events). You can get additional log events by specifying one of the tokens in a subsequent call.

Comment: Thank you for answer. However, I also saw the link you gave me. I do not know how to use the token to get the full log. where is the token? How can I create or initiate it? can you help me?

Comment: You are discarding the token by the way you are iterating `for a3 in logs.get_log_events(logGroupName=a1name, logStreamName=a2name)['events']`... You need to capture and examine the *entire* response to `get_log_events()`, not just the array of actual events.

Comment: Sorry I'm late for feedback.
Thanks to you, I found out the way.
I had to repeat executing the 'get_log_events' method according to nextBackWardToken or nextForWardToken information in the first result of get_log_events.
I wanna post modified code but I can't do that in comment.
Thank you Michael !

Comment: @bsofte: Share you final code adding it as an answer to this post or modify your original post and add it as an Update.